# Can't save byte[] array data to database in C#. It's saving 0x

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, webforms

I am trying to upload a file and save it's binary content to my database field. Each time I try to save, it simply enters the database as `0x`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<form id="frmDefault" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileInput" runat="server" style="margin: 8px 0 13px 0;" /><br />
    <asp:textbox rows="5" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" id="description" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload File" runat="server" 
        onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
</form>
```

I establish the variable:

```
HttpPostedFile file = fileInput.PostedFile;
```

And, it hits this function:

```
LoadFile(gAttachmentContentID, file.InputStream, trn);
```

Which is defined as:

```
public static void LoadFile(Guid gAttachmentContentID, Stream stm, IDbTransaction trn)
{
            const int BUFFER_LENGTH = 40 * 1024;
            byte[] binFILE_POINTER = new byte[32];
            //Testing check out check in
            // 01/20/2006 Paul.  Must include in transaction
            SqlProcs.spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_InitPointer(gAttachmentContentID, ref binFILE_POINTER, trn);

            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stm))
            {
                int nFILE_OFFSET = 0;
                byte[] binBYTES = reader.ReadBytes(BUFFER_LENGTH);

                while (binBYTES.Length > 0)
                {
                    // 08/14/2005 Paul.  gID is used by Oracle, binFILE_POINTER is used by SQL Server. 
                    // 01/20/2006 Paul.  Must include in transaction
                    SqlProcs.spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset(gAttachmentContentID, binFILE_POINTER, nFILE_OFFSET, binBYTES, trn);
                    nFILE_OFFSET += binBYTES.Length;
                    binBYTES = reader.ReadBytes(BUFFER_LENGTH);
                }
            }
}
```

How can I read the correct contents in order to save the entire file to the database?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

```
    #region spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset
    /// <summary>
    /// spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset
    /// </summary>
    public static void spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset(Guid gID, byte[] binFILE_POINTER, Int32 nFILE_OFFSET, byte[] byBYTES)
    {
        DbProviderFactory dbf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory();
        using ( IDbConnection con = dbf.CreateConnection() )
        {
            con.Open();
            using ( IDbTransaction trn = con.BeginTransaction() )
            {
                try
                {
                    using ( IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand() )
                    {
                        cmd.Transaction = trn;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        if ( Sql.IsOracle(cmd) )
                            cmd.CommandText = "spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOff";
                        else
                            cmd.CommandText = "spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset";
                        IDbDataParameter parID               = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@ID"              , gID                );
                        IDbDataParameter parFILE_POINTER     = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@FILE_POINTER"    , binFILE_POINTER    );
                        IDbDataParameter parMODIFIED_USER_ID = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@MODIFIED_USER_ID",  Security.USER_ID  );
                        IDbDataParameter parFILE_OFFSET      = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@FILE_OFFSET"     , nFILE_OFFSET       );
                        IDbDataParameter parBYTES            = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@BYTES"           , byBYTES            );
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    trn.Commit();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    trn.Rollback();
                    throw(new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: When you debug, what's the value of `Request.Files`? Also, you can just use `fileInput.PostedFile` instead of looping through the `Request.Files` collection

Comment: How do I check `Request.Files`?  I looked in locals but didn't see it.  It may be a non-issue now because I have removed the Request and loop as you have suggested, and I am simply referencing the file via `HttpPostedFile file = fileInput.PostedFile;`.  The record still gets inserted into the database, but still only with the contents `0x`.  How can I make it read the whole file into the database?

Comment: Have you tested your stored procedure to see if it writes the data correctly?

Comment: @Corey The stored procedure was already in use before, and seems to have been working properly.  I am simply trying to re-use it, here.

Comment: I am trying to upload a PNG image.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: The contents of the buffer shouldn't matter to the database.  Have you tried writing the data to a disk file to see if it's coming through correctly?

Comment: No, I am not sure how to do that.  Is `binBYTES` the variable that I am supposed to check?  Can I do a `Debug.Print()` on it?  I tried something like that before but it wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't actually understand this code very well...  Does anyone have any idea why it calls `_InitPointer` then `_WriteOffset`?  I simply want to store the binary contents of the file into the database, why might it require two different stored procedures to do so?

Comment: SqlProcs seems to be an object or class to encapsulate your stored procedures, this seems to be custom made, so we don't know how it works. I haven't used SQL Server and .NET to store binary data, but if the query is built using simple strings, then the binary data must be escaped of any escape character the database uses.

Comment: I have added the method `spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset` from the SQLProcs file to the question; will that help you determine what is wrong with the program?

Comment: I think what it's trying to do is fetch and write the data in chunks.  It uses _InitPointer and _WriteOffset to write one buffer-full of data at a time.

Comment: Thanks, Ann.  That sounds like a good guess.  Any idea why it would only be saving the first two characters (`0x`)?

Comment: I don't think that's the first 2 chars - I think that's a single hex zero. You've looked at the underlying database table, right? The other file entries don't appear like that?  (It's been a long time since I looked at binary data in a database!)   Also, can you verify (through debugging) that `binBYTES` has a non-zero length?

Comment: @AnnL. binBYTES.length does = 0.  What does this mean?

Comment: Just for the heck of it, before creating the binary reader, insert the line `stm.Position = 0;`.  See if that makes any difference.  I'm wondering whether you're getting either an empty stream or a stream that has already been read through and is positioned at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem, that is, the first time the image was saved correctly on the database side, but if subsequently validation failed and then I tried to save the image again after entering valid data I would get `0x` in the image column. To solve that I did what [@Ann L.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943333/cant-save-binary-data-to-database-in-c-sharp#comment21040844_14943333) said:

```
byte[] photo = null;

if(model.Photo != null)
{
    var stream = model.Photo.InputStream;
    stream.Position = 0;

    using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(model.Photo.InputStream))
    {
        photo = br.ReadBytes(model.Photo.ContentLength);
    }
}
```