# How to output binary data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, binary, webforms

I am having trouble saving my file into binary into my database and so, to debug, I am trying to view the contents of the binary.  I have tried this:

```
file.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, size);
Debug.Print("binary=" + fileData);
```

It outputs this:

```
binary=System.Byte[]
```

How can I see the actual data which should look like `0x78421824794783741237FJKHASJKH` etc?

In my database, it only goes in as `0x` (which is the larger problem I am trying to solve).

Comment: possible duplicate of [byte\[\] to hex string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/byte-to-hex-string) EDIT: FYI, the reason you're getting "System.Byte[]" as your output is that's simply the `ToString()` representation of the byte array; since the representation is a bit arbitrary (Base 2? Base 16? Base 64?) Also, I'm assuming you want hexadecimal output, but your "should look like" example includes invalid characters ("JKHS"), but I guess that was just you mashing on the keyboard. :)

Comment: Do you want to see it as a bunch of byte values?  Ones and zeros?  Base64?  What?

Comment: Yes, I just want to make sure there is actual data in there; because it's only going in my database as `0x` and there should be a bunch of numbers (binary code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply trying to make sure the data is there, the easiest way is probably to output it in Base64 encoding.  Something like:

```
byte[] foo = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(foo);
Console.WriteLine(base64);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/b9RCgv)

If there were no data (basically a `Byte[0]`), then `base64` would be an empty string.

Comment: Awesome, so that gives me `binary=iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE...`.  Can I just save that in my database and it will output properly?  How can I save the data to a database?  Currently, when I try to save it, it only stores `0x`.  Do you happen to have any idea?  Thanks for at least showing me this.

Comment: Sure, you could save that data in your database as a string (usually `varchar` or `text`).  You'd have to of course convert it back into a `Byte[]` with `Convert.FromBase64String(dbValue)` when loading it.  However, many databases support storing byte arrays natively, so technically you might not need to serialize the data at all.  Your choice.

Comment: I am using an existing stored procedure which uses a SQL image column to store the data.  It works for other pages, but not for this new thing that I am trying to create.  I can't figure out why it's only saving `0x`...

Comment: You'd probably want to post the code that saves the `Byte[]`, as well as the stored procedure.  I'd recommend posting a new question, and be sure to tag it with the appropriate database system you're using.

Comment: I already have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943333/cant-save-binary-data-to-database-in-c-sharp but no one seems to know what the problem is so far...

Comment: @user1477388 Using Base 64 is a good option, if you use simple string queries and don't want to escape your data, the tradeoff is that it occupies around 30% more than binary data, but it may be worth the loss.