# Updating database Image just stores 0x

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, image, sql-update

I have a table that stores information of users, which is filled by loading a XML file. 
In that table, I have an Image type column that is for all users set as "null" in the XML file.
The problem comes when I try to update that column and set an image, it just stores "0x".

This is the table:

```
create table User(
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50),
foto IMAGE,
email VARCHAR(100))
```

This is my update code:

```
protected void addFoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Byte[] imgByte = null;
    if (file_upload.PostedFile != null)
    {
        HttpPostedFile File = file_upload.PostedFile;
        File.InputStream.Position = 0;
        imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
        File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
    }
    string sql = "update User set foto = @foto where email= @email";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con.getConexion()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Txtemail.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foto", imgByte);
        con.open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.close();
    }
}
```

I tried adding

```
File.InputStream.Position = 0;
```

as the answer in this post, but still didn't work.

[Can't save byte[] array data to database in C#. It's saving 0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943333/cant-save-byte-array-data-to-database-in-c-its-saving-0x)

I also tried with the column type VARBINARY(MAX) with this code:

```
string sql = "update User set foto = @foto where email= @email";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con.getConexion()))
{
   Stream fs = file_upload.PostedFile.InputStream;
   BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
   Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Txtemail.Text.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@foto", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
   con.open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.close();
}
```

Which just stored 0x000000... And finally, I also tried adding directly an image with:

```
System.Drawing.Image imag = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file_upload.PostedFile.InputStream);
cmd.Parameters.Add("foto", SqlDbType.Binary, 0).Value = ConvertImageToByteArray(imag, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

with no result.

Here are the values of the file_upload while debugging:

[image: Debug console of the file_upload]

I find it odd that it has a posted file but no bytes...

If anyone can please tell me what I'm doing wrong I would be really grateful, and also excuse me if my English is not perfect.

Comment: Use a size for the varbinary field. .Add("@binaryValue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000)

Comment: @LuisDiego Can you check if this is null: file_upload.PostedFile? By stepping through the code?

Comment: @zaitsman no, it returns this value "{System.Web.HttpPostedFile}"

Comment: @Luba I added what you said in the line "cmd.Parameters.Add("@foto", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000).Value = bytes;" but it still stores 0x in the database.

Comment: @zaitsman I added the debug console, if you could please tell me whats going on in there...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was doing in the Page_Load a PostBack that refreshed the page in order to show the file's name, but at the same time it reset the PostedFile to nothing.

My solution was to make a global HttpPostedFile variable that stores the posted file in the PostBack for future usage.